# How do I define an alternate fallback in ~/.ssh/config?

Tags: ssh, configuration, ssh-config

I have a number of entries in `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host github.com
  Hostname github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github

Host mydomain.com
  User name
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Host full.name@work.com
  Hostname work.com
  User full.name
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/work_rsa
```

If none match, the default fallback is `id_rsa`. But I'd like a different fallback. The following attempt failed, because it catches everything, overriding any previous settings.

```
Host '*'
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/fallback
```

What is the correct way to express "none of the above"?

Comment: based on https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16571 I was thinking of defining Host '*' at the top

Comment: What happens if you just put `IdentityFile ~/.ssh/fallback` outside of a `Host` block?

Answer (score 0):

Move your fallback to the bottom. SSH takes the parameter value from the first matching `Host` block.

Since `Host *` will match everything, you want it last. Otherwise, SSH will always pick its `IdentityFile`.

```
Host github.com
  Hostname github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github

Host mydomain.com
  User name
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Host full.name@work.com
  Hostname work.com
  User full.name
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/work_rsa

Host *
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/fallback
```